# Java Mail is it possible to show users email in from field?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I am creating a contact form and was wondering if it is possible to show the user's email in the "from "field in a contact email box. I am using java mail api.

Now it looks like this

[image]

can I show users' emails instead of grazerteamroma@gmail.com?
It seems like a can`t get access to a user's to account to send the mail from their account, am I right?

Comment: That looks like gmail displaying the name instead of an email address if that address already is in the recipient's contacts. I don't think there's anything you can do to avoid that as a sender.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca so if a user sends me an email from a contact form, i should just put his email in the letter so i know whom to respond. yeap?

Comment: Oh, wait, I misunderstood the situation. You could try to change the sender address to the user address, but I'm not sure how gmail would react to that (this is a problem with gmail, not with code). So yeah, putting the user's address in the mail body would probably be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Java Mail is an API to talk to the backend (Mail User Agent to Mail Transport Agent communication). It is not related to presenting the mails to users at all.

So of course it is possible to users' email on the screen, be it the sender, the recipient or else. But this is a UI rendering issue, not Java Mail.
In other words: You are barking up the wrong tree.

But since you are asking:

- Send email - [here are examples](https://netcorecloud.com/tutorials/examples-for-sending-emails-from-javamail-api/)
- Receive email - [here are examples](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-receiving-email-using-java-mail-api)

In case your question is just about how Google Mail can print the name of the recipient independently of the email address, it probably parses this (recipient/originator) string:

```
Alfred Neuman <Neuman@BBN-TENEXA>
```

See the specification for email messages: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z10

Comment: so how can i put users email in a sender field?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to set the sender address without the email server/provider.
Try replyTo Field in your code.

you can try replyTo of MimeMessage class.
Here is the spring version MimeMessageHelper class, you can set it using MimeMessage also.

```
    public void sendEmail(Mail mail) 
    {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
            mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(mail.getMailSubject());
            mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail.getMailFrom()));
            mimeMessageHelper.setTo(mail.getMailTo());
            mimeMessageHelper.setText(mail.getMailContent());
            mimeMessageHelper.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress("anupamXXXX@gmail.com"));
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessageHelper.getMimeMessage());
        } 
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Using above code receiver will receive with replyto address on which he directly reply.
[image: Gmail preview]